# Why cant i use .mp4 and .jpg files in my Xamarin Forms Android project?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

In my project (under Drawables) I have .png, .jpg and .mp4 files but when I run my project the .png files are the only ones who are successfully being used in the app. If I screenshot how for instance a .mp4 looks compared to the .png file it looks like this. The .jpg file is also looking like the .mp4 file (white).

[image]

When I right-click the files and check the build action they are all set on "AndroidResource". I add the resources both through my XAML file and code directly with the same outcome.

I am following this guide where I try to implement a video-background in xamarin.forms.android: https://www.junian.net/2017/03/fullscreen-video-background-control-for-xamarin-forms.html
Any idea why it isn't working and why the solution cannot recognize/find these files?

Comment: both JPG and PNG should be supported.  MP4 is not.  See https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/images/

Comment: @Jason https://www.junian.net/2017/03/fullscreen-video-background-control-for-xamarin-forms.html I am following this guide and they seem to be using a mp4.

Comment: please edit your question to include that significant detail.  I assumed you were just trying to use an Image control, since you didn't provide any code or specifics about what you are doing

Comment: Done @Jason. Edited

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is right on the tutorial you referenced:

> ...remember that video file on Android need to be stored under Assets directory...

You are adding your `.mp4` as a `Resources/Drawables`, you need to add it within the Android `Assets`

- [Xamarin Guilde to Using Android Assets](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/application_fundamentals/resources_in_android/android-assets/)